# MYSQL8. Why is transaction 2 locked in this situation?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

#### READY

```sql
# ready
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col_1 INT,
    INDEX idx_a (col_1)
) ENGINE = innodb;
```

| id | col_a |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 4 | 25 |

#### Trnasaction 1

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE col_1 = 15
FOR UPDATE;
```

#### Trnasaction 2

```sql
START TRANSACTION;

# LOCK
INSERT INTO table_a (col_1) VALUES (10);
```

#### performance_schema.data_locks;

| LOCK_TYPE | LOCK_MODE | LOCK_STATUS | LOCK_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TABLE | IX | GRANTED |  |
| RECORD | X | GRANTED | 15, 2 |
| RECORD | X,REC_NOT_GAP | GRANTED | 2 |
| RECORD | X,GAP | GRANTED | 20, 3 |

I wonder why Transaction2 is locked

In LOCK_MODE=x, Isn't LOCK_DATA=15,2 in the 11-14 range?

Comment: What happens if you change `col_1 = 15` to `col_1 = 20`?

Answer (score 0):

Here need one Insert Intention Lock between (10, 15] on Repeatable reads isolation level. Also need to lock **col_1 value 15 on index idx_a**

refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-insert-intention-locks